# JBoss AS7 @Inject bean into valve

Tags: jboss, cdi, inject, tomcat-valve

Is it possible to `@Inject` a stateless session bean into a subclass of `AuthenticatorBase`?

I'm using JBoss as 7.1.1.

My code looks like this:

...

```
public class myValve extends AuthenticatorBase {

    @Inject AuthController controller;

    //some code ...

}
```

Using the controller object leads to `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If controller is null it means that the myValve object itself was not injected.

It is possible to add an existing object to the CDI context retroactively, for example with this code:

```
public <T> void addToCDI(T object) {
    BeanManager beanManager = BeanManagerProvider.getInstance().getBeanManager();
    AnnotatedType<T> annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType((Class<T>)bject.getClass());
    InjectionTarget<T> injectionTarget = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(annotatedType);
    CreationalContext<T> context = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);
    injectionTarget.inject(object, context);
}
```

After the execution of this code the injections have been performed.